# ELO ranking system: what's a good start rank?

Tags: math, statistics

I'm looking to implement an ELO ranking system. I've read the wikipedia articles and I'm confused about the start rank for players who enter the system at a later point. The common solution is to use a provisional ranking system but I'm curious if anyone can point me to specific numeric details:

- what K value do new players get?
- how long does a player stay in provisional mode?
- how does K value change as rank changes?

I'm sure there are many variations, I'd just like to know actual numbers for a system that someone has implemented successfully.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: This might be more appropriate on http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: My intuition tells me the median is the best prior. Anyway: a fresh entry has low weight and is very volatile, so the initial ranking does not matter much.

Comment: All your questions are answered on the Wikipedia article. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system

Comment: The wikipedia article doesn't really give a whole system's explanation  on how all three of the above points are set. It gives different systems and details 1 or 2 out of 3 points I asked.